# Install Sony Vegas 10 on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sony-vegas

When I try to install Sony Vegas 10e on Windows 2003 the setup says it's not supported and aborts. The same setup supports Windows XP SP3, so it should work on Windows 2003 Server R2 SP2 fully updated and with .net 4 installed.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can install Vegas (well, not only Vegas, but virtually anything) using "modified" .msi install package. You shall need a .msi edit tool like Orca (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905/EN-US/). 
When setup says "Operation system not supported" go to a temporary file storage (most common path is C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Temp). 
Find the most recent .msi file and copy it somewhere. For clarity I shall name this "file.msi" Quit the setup. 
Launch Orca (or whatever) and find "LaunchCondition" table there. Modify the "Condition" field to a "VersionNT>=501" value and save transform file to a "file.mst" in the directory saved file.msi lies (Transform->Generate transform in Orca). 
Launch the command shell (WinKey+R->cmd) and change directory to the one your .msi and file.mst is placed.
Type "msiexec /i "file.msi" TRANSFORMS=file.mst". Done.

I have absolutely no idea whether this method is legal. EULA prohibits modifying program files, but no modification to the files in question is being made. Maybe you should consult with someone. I do no know how the installed program shall work (worked like a charm for me), but you will be able to install Vegas, as you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's not exactly true... that just because it will install on WinXP, it should install on Windows Server 2003.

For example... Vegas 10 isn't compatible with XP 64.

> Microsoft® Windows® XP 32-bit SP3
>
> Windows Vista® 32-bit or 64-bit SP2
>
> or Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit

That is all that Sony Vegas 10 is compatible with, according to them.  Which means the installer could simply reject any other OS it is installed on.  Now, you didn't say whether you are talking about a W2k3 IA-32, X64, or IA-64 install.  I suppose it could detect the IA-32 Intel 32 bit version as some kind of Windows XP 32 bit version... because people have installed Vegas 10 on Windows server 2008, which is based on Windows NT 6.x... and Vegas 10 supports both 32 bit and 64 bit for Windows NT 6.x.

I'm guessing you did not install the 32 bit version of Windows Server 2003?

**EDIT** you asked for ideas... does this qualify?

Comment: @ZEE so... which version of Windows Server 2003 do you have installed?  32 bit for Intel?  (IA-32)  64 bit for AMD?  (x64) or 64 bit for Intel?  (IA-64)?  Come on... no need to abandon your question.

Comment: Thx for you answer... but I must say it's a no answer... What I mean is that untill now all software I've used with Windows XP SP3 I succeed in using with Server 2003 also... In fact for the desktop use the OS's are very similar... with very minor tweaks I installed all programs I want... I'd like to know if someone has an idea how to circunvent the setup "problem" in windows 2003...

Comment: I'm not quitting... I'm very resilient (read stubborn)... after a few tests I'm almost succeeding in doing this... When I have a bit more time I'll try a few more ideas and if I succeed I'll post the result here...

Comment: @Zee.  I'm not asking you to quit.  I'm asking you which version of Windows server 2003 you have... because it doesn't matter how resiliant you are.  Sony Vegas 10 will not work with Windows XP 64 bit, or Windows server 2003 64 bit.  It Will work with Windows XP 32 bit, and therefore it should also work with Windows Server 2003 32 bit.  So, if you are using Windows server 2003 64 bit, then this isn't a No Answer... it's just an answer you don't want.

Comment: Windows 2003... I use all 32 bit versions... Standard, Enterprise, Data-Center... for 64 bits I only use Windows 7 and Windows 2008... Any ideas on the subject!?

Comment: @Zee.  Wow.  That's quite expensive.  All three of those?  You mean, you are trying to install Sony Vegas 10 on three different Windows Server 2003 installations?  I'm curious.  When you contacted Sony Support, for the product support you paid for with your copy of SOny Vegas 10... what did they say?

Comment: @Zee in this long-ish thread http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/24/921458 although Sony did not support Vegas 10 being installed on XP64, a user got it to work. Essentially, he started with an install of Windows 7, and installed Vegas 10 on it.  He then used PCMover Pro http://www.laplink.com/pcmover/pcmoverpro.html to move the installation to XP 64.  So, you might want to try the same thing.

Comment: Hi Bon... I test some choose software packages in a number of OS for investigation purposes.

This time Sony Vegas 10 was choose because of a requirement from 1 of our clients and because after a quick analysis of the installed software in Windows 7 we saw no reason to not work in 2003 
(the reason for Win2K3 Enterprise is that is a 32bit system and supports 16Gb of memory in this particular case)

Comment: I have already succeeded in putting Vegas at work in Win2K3 and it is working with minor glitches... Works fine!

If there is interest I can make a small manual of the procedure to install Sony Vegas Pro in Windows 2003. ATT*** Sony says this can't be done and do not recommend it...